# Scope for user with most photos, rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models, `user` and `pin`.

User `has_many` pins and Pin `belongs_to`User.

I want to make a query where I list the users with more pins.

```
 @top = User.find_by(Pin.count)
```

This wont work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: `@top = User.includes(:pins).where("pins.count = ?", and_ur_condition)`

Comment: why do you mean by more pins, greater than 20 or wht exactly?

Comment: @Sontya order by the most pins to the less pins

Comment: try this in your user model `has_many :pins, -> { order(:count) }`

Comment: But that will affect all of the users, and I need a separate ordering in the controller for a specific role in User . Thanks @Sontya

Comment: `@top = User.includes(:pins).order('count DESC')`

Comment: @Sontya, ``order('count DESC')`` won't work, there is no ``count`` column on any table that we know.

Comment: Exactly, PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "count" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT "users".* FROM "users"   ORDER BY count DESC

Comment: `User.includes(:pins).group("users.id").order("count(pins.id)")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you are asking for:

```
 @top = User.joins(:pins).group("users.id").order('COUNT(pins.id)')
```

Comment: Hi @dgilperez, I'm getting this error:

PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function